# Querying with a last occurrence similar to the current record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this scenario

[image: database scenario]

I need to return the last and second to last records with the same type_id searching all records in the table

Example: 
Article ID  |  Last Article ID that uses the same type_id on your details of the Article ID from the first column

With this data above would be the following return:

```
Article ID   -  Last Article ID with the same type_id
4               -                   2
3               -                 null
```

How can be the query to return this result?

Thanks

Comment: And which Mysql version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `lag()` and `row_number()`:

```
select
    article_id,
    last_article_id
from (
    select 
        article_id,
        lag(article_id) over(partition by type_id order by details_id) last_article_id,
        row_number() over(partition by type_id order by details_id desc) rn
    from mytable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 5.x Version of mysql

You can try

```
SELECT
  IF(rnk = 1,Article_ID,0)  article_id
  ,MAX(IF(rnk = 2,Article_ID,NULL)) last_article_id
FROM
  (SELECt 
    t1.Article_ID
    ,if(@id <> Type_id, @rnk:=0,@rnk:= @rnk)
    ,@rnk  := @rnk +1 rnk
    ,@id := Type_id  Type_ID
  FROM
    (SELECT * FROM article_Detail ORDER By Type_ID,Article_ID DESC) t1,(SELECT @rnk := 1) r1,
    (SELECT @id := 0) i
  ) articcledetail
GROUP BY Type_ID;
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE article_Detail (   
DETAIL_ID INT,  
Article_ID INT,  
Type_ID INT);   
INSERT INTO article_Detail values (100,1,1),(101,2,1),(102,3,2),(103,4,1);
```

I am ordering your Articlwe details table by their type_id and then article ID to get the highest article id as first entry to rank it.